# Using laptop's monitor as a HDMI screen

Tags: laptop, hdmi, satellite

I have a satellite TV decoder and a laptop. Is it possible to plug the decoder's HDMI into my laptop's HDMI plug and use it as a monitor somehow?

Edit: I have an Asus S550C but I don't know what kind of HDMI port I have on this.

Answer (score 5):

Only if your laptop supports HDMI-input, which is highly unlikely. You would need to get a USB video-input dongle of some sort.

Answer (score 5):

No.

Laptop displays are generally only wired to receive signals from the built in graphics system on your laptop. Additionally hdmi display ports on are unidirectional meaning that they are output only, they cannot receive a signal, they can only send signals.

--

Okay, apparently there are *some* laptops that do have HDMI input such as the [Clevo 8100](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-104615-using-a-laptop-to-play-ps3-through-hdmi) and it sounds like they're more common than I thought. Check if you have an input port on your laptop, though if it is a cheaper laptop it is unlikely that you do.

Otherwise you may want to look into [HDMI capture tools](http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/uk/products/intensity/) and hardware.

Googling for "HDMI record USB" shows an assortment of devices that would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been going around for years, As it is "Highly" Uncommon to find a laptop with an HDMI Input, The answer to your question Is Yes if you have the correct Laptop. Or If you purchase A HDMI to VGA Adapter of Ebay, Amazon Or any other of the sort. If you own a Capture Card Such as Elgato, Dazzle and other. You would only need to get a Video Encoder to Bring up the Display. The hardware needed prices can be between 20-100 AUD

Comment: You might consider stop using the tag line "REG_EDIT Out" it really does not conform to the format we expect.

Comment: Please do not use signatures and tag lines, you get your name below every answer you post and can keep personal information and "shout outs" in your profile.